# IIS8 looking for web.config in virtual directory rather than app root

Tags: asp.net, iis-8

I have a Virtual Application in IIS8, http://localhost:80/application/, the files for which are located in C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application. There is a web.config file in the ~/application/ folder.

Under the application, I have a virtual directory, http://localhost:80/application/vdir/, the files for which are located in J:\virtual_directory.

When I try to access a file under the /vdir/ directory, I get HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error, it says it cannot read configuration file at \?\J:\virtual_directory\web.config

Why is it looking for the web.config file there, rather than C:\inetpub\wwwroot\application\web.config? I have never had this problem in IIS 7, this is my first time setting this up on a Windows 2012 server.

(Note: J: is mapped to a shared folder on the network. Not sure if that makes a difference?)

Comment: There is only virtual directory or application. Don't invent something like "virtual application". Mapped drives are not supported by any version of IIS. Since web.config is allowed at any level, IIS will try to read it from any level.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, turns out I had to do two things:

1. Create the virtual directory using the UNC path (\\servername\sharedfolder) rather than the mapped drive letter
2. use a network account in the Physical Path Credentials under advanced settings rather than the default Pass-Through Authentication

Comment: How do you create virtual directory using UNC path?? IIS doesn't allow this

Comment: To be honest? I wasn't aware that it wasn't supposed to work, so I just did it. It's possible our servers at work have some extra server-farm type of extensions to IIS, I'm not actually a network person.